# How to use QtMultimedia on Qt 6.3.0?

Tags: qt, qtmultimedia

I tried to add some sound effects to my project, and when I tried "QT += multimedia", the compiler told me it was an unknown module in qt, like this

[image]

How can I fix this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: How did you install Qt? Did you select the Qt Multimedia submodule?